# EclipseLink logging level in GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, java.util.logging

I have set glassfish 3.1.2's logging level as follows:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.session = INFO
org.eclipse.persistence.session.file = INFO
```

But I do get the following output of level `FINER`:

```
[#|2015-11-19T11:31:37.322+0100|FINER|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/aip/lib/jpa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_primary.connection|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|client released|#]
```

Comment: This is the EclipseLink logging, not GlassFish logging

Answer (score 1):

The message with level FINER comes from eclipselink JPA implementation, which is a component of glassfish, but configured separately. You need to configure this logging in [persistence.xml](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)